# Hex Datetime convert to python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, hex

Datetime in Hex needs to be converted to python datetime.

I require to convert the Hex in database like `0xA87B00DDC632` which we know is actually a datetime. I require to extract that and convert it into a python datetime object.

I am using lambda function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

hextodate = lambda input_hex : datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1,0,0) \

                             + datetime.timedelta(int(format(input_hex, 'x')[:4].upper(),16)) \

                             + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(format(input_hex, 'x')[4:].upper(),16)/300)

 

hextodate(0xA87B00DDC632)


Out[0]: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 2, 13, 27, 27)
```

Comment: Is this a common format to store date&time? Looks sort of arbitrary, esp. the division by 300